# Swift 2 Core Data: delete object ok! but no Refresh Row in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift2

This code works correctly, deletes in Core Data. Table view set DELETE in red to the right but does not delete the row in the table view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let manageObject: NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
moc.deleteObject(manageObject)

    do {
        try moc.save()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to save")
        return
    }
}
```

If I do stop the App and then I run it again, the table view do not sample row deleted and sample rows that they remain.

Comment: have you tried to reload tableview ?

Comment: Have you implemented the FRC delegate methods (and set the FRC's delegate property)?  There's boilerplate code that should trigger the relevant table view updates.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the item explicitly by adding

```
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

after `moc.deleteObject()`

or add the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
  self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
  switch type {
  case .Insert:
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
  case .Delete:
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
  case .Update:
    self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
  case .Move:
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
  }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
  self.tableView.endUpdates()
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Error     libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught excepto of type NSException

Comment: let manageObject: NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
        
        moc.deleteObject(manageObject)
        
        do {
            try moc.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save")
            return
        }
        // Refresh the table view to indicate that it's deleted
        reInicio()

Comment: func reInit () {
        self.viewDidLoad()
    }

Comment: self.tableView.endUpdates() gives me the working solution, thx!!